# MSVC2012 - does it have 10 toolset?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I need to compile some CUDA code with MSVC2010 but I might consider buying MSVC2012 instead of MSVC2010 if I can switch toolset to 10 from MSVC2012 options.

Is that possible or MSVC2012 just ships with the 11 toolset?

Comment: It has lots of toolsets, depends on what you got installed.  You ought to check if your cuda build tools support VS2012.

Comment: no it doesn't, but if I install VS2012 ONLY, will there be a v10 toolset in a project's options? Or just the v11 toolset?

Comment: Not if VS2010 is not installed on that machine.  The VS2012 installer doesn't include the tool chain for VS2010.  You only get the v100 toolset if VS2010 is already present on the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you can only get the v100 toolset in VS2012 if VS2010 was already installed on the machine.  So high odds that you'll need to choose VS2010 if the Cuda tool-chain you use doesn't support VS2012 yet.

A quick google turned up [this blog post](http://blog.norture.com/2012/10/gpu-parallel-programming-in-vs2012-with-nvidia-cuda/), showing you how to setup VS2012 to run the NVidia Cuda 5.0 tool-chain.  It isn't clear from your question whether this applies.  Do take a look at this, VS2012 is an excellent VS2010 service pack ;)